# Creating a new column by checking multiple elif statements in python dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a new string column `FailureType` by checking the content of `Reason` string column. I am checking whether column `Reason` contains `Trip,Lock,Fail` and so on. If 'Reason' contains `Trip` then new column `FailureType` should be populated with `Trip` so on so forth.

## Defining function for the categorization of the failures

```
def failure_cat(df):
    
    for reason in df['Reason']:
        
        df['Reason'].str.contains("trip") == True
        
        if any(df['Reason'].str.contains("trip")):
            df['FailureType'] = "Trip"
        
        elif any(df['Reason'].str.contains("lock")):
            df['FailureType'] = "Locked Out"
              
        elif any(df['Reason'].str.contains("force")):
            df['FailureType'] = "Forced Outage"
        
        elif any(df['Reason'].str.contains("Blow")):
            df['FailureType'] = "Blown Out"  
    
        else:
            df['FailureType'] = "Other" 
    
        return df

cap_bank['FailureType']
```

Produces the result:

```
0      Trip
1      Trip
2      Trip
3      Trip
4      Trip
5      Trip
6      Trip
7      Trip
8      Trip
9      Trip
10     Trip
11     Trip
12     Trip
13     Trip
14     Trip
15     Trip
16     Trip
17     Trip
18     Trip
19     Trip
20     Trip
21     Trip
22     Trip
```

The column 'Reason' looks like this:
0                                       cap. bank failed
1                                bank has tripped twice.
2                                bank has tripped twice.
3            cap bank tripped and locked out of service.
4       failed insulators and reactor causing fire in...
5                  repair problems with cap bank triping
6         01/07/08: forced trip occurred at about 11:00.
7                       cap bank tripped and locked out.
8                      failed 351a relay xfmr protection
9                      failed 351a relay xfmr protection
10                         repair slow tripping cap bank
11                         repair slow tripping cap bank
12                         repair slow tripping cap bank
13     repair slow tripping cap bank. will replace ro...
14     repair slow tripping cap bank. will replace ro...
15      failed insulators and reactor causing fire in...

So, I am checking whether the column 'Reason' has trip,lock,etc. in it and based on that I want to populate the the newly created column 'FailureType'. But all the rows are getting populated with the value `Trip` which is not the case. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does your sample data look like? In your for loop, you appear to be iterating through "reasons" even though the field is just "Reason" but then you're just looking directly back at df['Reason'], so the for loop is superfluous.

Comment: I edited it. My issue is that for all the records in the dataframe, the newly created column is getting populated with 'Trip', which is not true. So, the first if condition is getting evaluated to True all the time.

Comment: What does the typical input `df` look like though, not the result you are getting? It kind of looks like you should be doing something like `if reason == "trip"` instead of `if any(df['Reason'].str.contains("trip"))` but I am speculating.

Comment: It is a very large data set. The column 'Reason' looks like this                              
0                                       cap. bank failed
1                                bank has tripped twice.
2                                bank has tripped twice.
3            cap bank tripped and locked out of service.
4       failed insulators and reactor causing fire in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the code

```
df['FailureType'] = "Trip"
```

It assigns the value `Trip` to all rows in the column `FailureType`. What I think is happening is the last row of the dataset contains `trip` which is causing the column to have value `Trip` when the loop ends.

What you want to do is use lambda instead, something like

```
def get_failure_type(reason):
    if 'trip' in reason:
       return 'Trip'
    elif 'lock' in reason:
        return 'Locked Out'
    return 'Other'

df['FailureType'] = df['Reason'].apply(lambda x: get_failure_type(x))
```

Comment: It worked out just the way I wanted it to be. Thanks a lot.